# Setting up a macro with imagej

Tags: imagej

I am trying to set up a macro in imagej. I am quite unfamiliar with the language it uses so I mostly work with the documentation.

I am trying to replicate a code I found in 1 paper.
So I have a .ijm file with the code. i press run but it throws an error here

```
macro "Morphometry [F7
{ title=getTitle();  morphometry(title,false);. }
```

And the error I am getting is

```
'{' Expected in line 7 macro "Morphometry<[>F7]
```

Comment: Please ask ImageJ-specific questions on the recommended channel, the image.sc forum: https://forum.image.sc as written in the imagej tag description here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors in the code, which will cause errors.

```
macro "Morphometry [F7]"
{ title=getTitle();  morphometry(title,false); }
```

Note 1) the closing quote to entitle the macro, 2) the removed period after the second semi-colon which would also cause an error.

When you get error messages in ImageJ, take a look at the pointy brackets, which enclose the part of code which ImageJ thinks is causing the error.